# jQuery: get each key value pair from a JSON?

Tags: jquery, json

so I got a JSON like

```
{key:value, key2:value2, key3:value3...}
```

I want to loop over each entry and get it's key and value so I can construct something like this

```
{list:[{key:value}, {key2:value2}, {key3:value3}]}
```

should I be using underscore instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
var list = $.map(data, function(val, key){
    var o = {};
    o[key] = val;
    return o;
})
var obj = {
    list: list
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dB5Wc/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `jQuery.each` function like below

```
var data = [ 
 {"Id": 10004, "PageName": "club"}, 
 {"Id": 10040, "PageName": "qaz"}, 
 {"Id": 10059, "PageName": "jjjjjjj"}
];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(data[i].PageName);
});​

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    alert(item.PageName);
});​
```

Comment: This is not an answer, the question is how to convert object to key value pair and i guess property names are not known

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a library in this situation.  This can be done with native JS:

```
var json = {key:"1", key2:"2", key3:"3"};

var result = {list:[]};
for(var field in json){
    if(json.hasOwnProperty(field)){
        var obj = {}
        obj[field] = json[field];
        result.list.push(obj);
    }
}

//result contains the desired array
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ygrG8/